# Yii db connection issue

Tags: php, yii

I am getting this error message:

> The table "Permissionactions" for active record class
>   "Permissionactions" cannot be found in the database.

```
  /var/www/html/YII/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(2310)

     private $_model;

     /**
      * Constructor.
     * @param CActiveRecord $model the model instance
      */
     public function __construct($model)
     {
        $this->_model=$model;

        $tableName=$model->tableName();
         if(($table=$model->getDbConnection()->getSchema()->getTable($tableName))===null)
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','The table "{table}" for active record class "{class}" cannot be found in the database.',
                 array('{class}'=>get_class($model),'{table}'=>$tableName)));
         if($table->primaryKey===null)
         {
             $table->primaryKey=$model->primaryKey();
             if(is_string($table->primaryKey) && isset($table->columns[$table->primaryKey]))
                 $table->columns[$table->primaryKey]->isPrimaryKey=true;
            elseif(is_array($table->primaryKey))
           {
               foreach($table->primaryKey as $name)
                {
                     if(isset($table->columns[$name]))
                        $table->columns[$name]->isPrimaryKey=true;
```

There is no any Permissionactions named table in my db. This is the main.php connection:

```
'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=xxxxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'xxxxxxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
         'dbpermissions' => array(
            'connectionString' => "mysql:host=xxxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx",
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'xxxxxxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'
        ),
```

Any idea why am I getting this ?

UPDATE:
This is the controller:

```
class MainController extends Controller {
    public $model;
    public function init(){
        $this->model = Permissionactions::model();
    }
...
```

and the Permissionsactions class (model):

```
class Permissionactions extends ActiveRecord{

    private $connection_permission; 
    //private $connection_invetory;

    /**
     * @see db connections from config/main.php
     */
    public function __construct(){
        $this->connection_permission =  Yii::app()->dbpermissions;
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__){
        return parent::model($className);
    }
....
```

On my localhost it works. But now I put it on a server and it shows me this error.

Comment: Permissionactions is a model class. any idea ?

Comment: maybe public function getDbConnection() {
    return Yii::app()->test;
}
 or cache?

Comment: getDbConnection(). ?? I don;t get it

Comment: Create a Permissionactions table for Model class Permissionactions in your database and changed tableName() return value to your database table name

Comment: I have an older Yii version in the server. I checked the CActiveRecod . Is there a way  to change smth in order to not modify this Class ?

Comment: What is tableName(){} returing for your Permissionactions Model

Answer (score 0):

Search thru your Code with your Editor/IDE function **Search in Files / search in Project** and locate the String

> Permissionactions

Provide some more Information about your Issue and your Config.